# How long does it take for a admissions decision to be made after a P.h.D interview

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, interview

how long does it take to get an admission decision after a Ph.D. interview? I had an interview for a P.h.D position in a school in the US with two professors in the faculty(neuroscience) and I was asked about my areas of research interest, I stated. one of the members on the panel is part of the department on which I intend to focus my research on. but I am not quite interested in her research, so I was asked if I went through her work I responded yes but I added that I found it a little complex and did not quite understand. is this a big red flag for me getting admitted?

Comment: The question title and the body of the question contain different questions.

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately depends on the school, department, and temperament of the faculty involved, and could be anything from days to weeks to longer. You're best served reaching out to admissions at the school you're applying to, or the department in question, and asking for a loose timeline. They won't be offended by such a request, and if they are unable to answer they'll tell you so.

As to the interview, most research is at least a little complex and difficult to understand. Academics are used to being told that, especially by incoming students. Much of the early part of one's PhD education is learning how to decipher the work of others in your field, so to expect somebody who hasn't even started that process to understand it fully is usually a stretch. The attempt is respected, however, and is a good sign for someone who took steps to prepare for their panel, even if they didn't fully grasp all of the details.